# Html2Pdf + Symfony + Docker : Unable to get the size of the image

Tags: symfony, docker, html2pdf

I have got a problem for generate a Pdf with HMTL2Pdf.
I use :

- Symfony framework
- spipu/html2Pdf
- Docker with a container for the app (8080) and a Minio container (9001) for files

I try to display an image on my pdf but i have the error : `Unable to get the size of the image [http://127.0.0.1:9001/events/photos/37652647-203b-4196-8792-6b5da989eddc.jpeg]`.

My twig template

```
{% for page in pages %}
<page backtop="20mm" backright="10mm" backbottom="20mm" backleft="10mm">
    <img src="{{ page.background|storage_url }}">
</page
{% endfor %}
```

My controller

```
public function handle(): string
{
    $template = $this->renderer->render('pdf/index.html.twig', [
        'pages' => $this->pageManager->findAll(),
    ]);

    $this->pdfCreator->create('L', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', array(10, 15, 10, 15));
    return $this->pdfCreator->generatePdf($template, "test");
}
```

My Service pdfCreator

```
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf as Html2Pdf;

final class PdfCreator implements PdfCreatorInterface
{
    /** @var Html2Pdf $pdf */
    private $pdf;

    public function create($orientation = null, $format = null, $lang = null, $unicode = null, $encoding = null, $margin = null): void
    {
        $this->pdf = new Html2Pdf($orientation, $format, $lang, $unicode, $encoding, $margin);
    }

    /**
     * @param $template
     * @param $name
     * @return string
     * @throws \Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException
     */
    public function generatePdf($template, $name): string
    {
        $this->pdf->writeHTML($template);
        return $this->pdf->Output($name.'.pdf');
    }
}
```

Note :

- If i delete `<img>`, my PDF is properly display
- My image path is correct because i can display it with the same way on a different page of my application

Can you please help me to display my image ? I can't use absolute path because my image come from the other container Minio (9001) so i don't know how to do

Comment: Just a quick idea: Instead of exposing the Minio Container you could access it via league/flysystem with S3 Adapter. Then have a small proxy controller on the php app that returns the image from there. 

Could you post your docker-compose.yml file, too?

Comment: After drinking a cup of coffee: The php container cant access the 9001 URL internally since 127.0.0.1 points to itsself always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was to try to use 9001 URL to access to my image so i made this that solved my problem :

- Get the content of my image
- Create temporary file with that content
- Display this temporary file in the pdf

My template

```
{% for page in pages %}
    <page backtop="20mm" backright="10mm" backbottom="20mm" backleft="10mm">
        <img src="/tmp/{{ page.background }}" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
    </page>
{% endfor %}
```

My controller

```
public function handle(FileUploader $fileUploader): string
{
    $pages = $this->pageManager->findAll();
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $fileUploader->makeTempFile($page->getBackground());
    }
    $template = $this->renderer->render('pdf/index.html.twig', [
        'pages' => $pages,
    ]);

    $this->pdfCreator->create('L', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', array(10, 15, 10, 15));
    return $this->pdfCreator->generatePdf($template, "test");
}
```

My service FileUploader

```
use Gaufrette\FilesystemInterface;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

final class FileUploader implements FileUploaderInterface
{
    private $filesystem;

    public function __construct(FilesystemInterface $filesystem)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function upload(File $file): string
    {
        $filename = Uuid::uuid4()->toString().'.'.$file->guessExtension();

        $this->filesystem->write($filename, file_get_contents($file->getPathname()));

        return $filename;
    }

    public function get(string $fileName)
    {
        return $this->filesystem->read($fileName);
    }

    public function makeTempFile(string $fileName)
    {
        $content = $this->get($fileName);
        file_put_contents(sys_get_temp_dir().'/'.$fileName, $content);
    }
}
```

And i add GD to my DockerFile php-fpm

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev git libicu-dev libpng-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql gd

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
```

And it works ! thanks for your help.